# Regex: Match IP address except when preceded by certain characters?

Tags: python, regex

This regex `([a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3`} almost doe the job of matching just IP addresses (v4 and v6) and nothing else, but unfortunately, for the text below and similar text, it also picks up the fields in **bold**:

---

> from mail.example.com (example.com. [213.239.250.131]) by 
>   mx.google.com with ESMTPS id
>   xc4si15480310lbb.82.2**014.10.26.06**.16.58 for  
>   (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  bits=128/128);
>   Sun, 26 Oct 2014 06:16:58 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Received: from ssservices1-1 (192.168.20.142) by mail.supershuttle.com
>   (192.168.20.110) with Microsoft SMTP Server id **14.2.347.0**; Tue, 21
>   Apr 2015
>
> Received: from ssservices1-1 (192.168.20.142) by mail.supershuttle.com
>   (192.168.20.110) with Microsoft SMTP (TLS) Server id **14.2.347.0**;
>   Tue, 21 Apr 2015
>
> Received: from plug.mysitehosted.com (plug.mysitehosted.com
>   [10.248.1.153])
>       (using TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA)
>       by **0.0.0.0**:2500 (trex/5.0.19);
>       Tue, 11 Mar 2014 06:14:03 GMT

---

What's the best approaching (I'll be using Python) for omitting these matches? Two are preceded by the text 'id', though in the first case, not *directly* preceding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
([a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4}|(?<!id )(?<!\.)\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b(?!\.)
```

You can try this.Through `lookaheads` we make sure the ip address is not preceded or followed by `.`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/3

Answer (score 2):

As an additional hint you could add positive forward and backward lookups. They will allow you to look what is before and after the match without consuming anything. Your IPs are always surrounded by `()` or `[]`, so you can try:

```
(?<=\[|\()your regex(?=\]|\))
```

This will match `your regex` in both:

```
(your regex)
[your regex]
```